# Optimizing large file download in python

Tags: python

I have a 1GB file I am trying to see how fast I can download (I have a few thousand of them I will eventually have to download). Here is how I am currently downloading it --

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, dest)
```

What would be the fastest way to download a single file in python?

Comment: All methods are going to take about the same amount of time. The bottleneck here is internet speed, which you can't really do anything about.

Comment: What if you were to download it in parallel chunks?

Comment: Will all the threads be sharing an internet connection?

Comment: Yes all the threads will be on the same computer.

Comment: `download it in parallel chunks` will work only if you are being throttled by the server and not by your ISP. If that's the case, throw multiprocessing at this problem, and download one file per process

Comment: Multi-threading will offer you nothing. See Roger Fan's note above.

Comment: @RogerFan may well be right but its worth tyring a couple of options if (1) these downloads are at your local company so its running at internal network speeds not internet speeds, (2) the remote server is doing per-download pacing but isn't paying attention to folks who do multiple connections in parallel.

Comment: Simple test: Try downloading two files at the same time. You can simply use two python processes to do this for now. If it takes twice as long then there's nothing you can really do. If it doesn't then you can probably speed it up somewhat with threading or multiprocessing.